# UTCDateTime::toDateTime() method returnig 1970 datetime

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm seeing something odd with UTCDateTime objects:

```
$dt = new UTCDateTime(time());
var_dump($dt);
```

Outputs:

```
object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#208 (1) {
  ["milliseconds"]=>
  int(1478644003)
}
```

OK, so this timestamp is 8th Nov 2016.

But when I do the following:

```
var_dump($dt->toDateTime());
```

Outputs:

```
object(DateTime)#206 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "1970-01-18 02:44:04.105000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

The date is reset to 1970 :( What might be the cause of this? Am I using these objects correctly? It should be a DateTime representation of the UTCDateTime - http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.todatetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any one step for your code

**STEP 1 :**

```
new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( (int) $timestamp * 1000 );
```

**STEP 2 :**

You can use below function instead of direct assigning. Example : **mongoDate('1542957787');**

```
function mongoDate( $timestamp = '' ) {

    if ( empty($timestamp) && $timestamp != 0 ) {
        return false;
    }


    if ( strlen( (string) $timestamp ) == 13 ) { // timestamp length in MilliSeconds
        return new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( (int) $timestamp );
    }

    return new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( (int) $timestamp * 1000 );

}
```